OV7670 QQVGA RGB565 config
Does anybody has register configuration for OV7670 QQVGA RGB565?
I found this but I'm not sure that it gives QQVGA resoltuion.
{REG_CLKRC, 0x80}, // double clock
{REG_COM11, 0x0A}, // enable auto 50/60Hz detect + exposure timing can be less...
{REG_COM7 , 0x04}, // RGB
{REG_COM15, 0xD0}, // RGB565

{REG_COM3, 0x04}, // DCW enable
{REG_COM14, 0x1a}, //pixel clock divided by 4, manual scaling enable, DCW and PCLK controlled by register
{REG_SCALING_XSC, 0x3a},
{REG_SCALING_YSC, 0x35},

{REG_SCALING_DCWCTR, 0x22},
{REG_SCALING_PCLK_DIV, 0xf2},
{REG_SCALING_PCLK_DELAY, 0x02},

{REG_HSTART, 24},
{REG_HSTOP, 6},
{REG_HREF, 36},

{REG_VSTART, 2},
{REG_VSTOP, 122},
{REG_VREF, 0},

{0xb0, 0x84}, // no clue what this is but it's most important for colors
{0x4f, 0x80},
{0x50, 0x80},
{0x51, 0x00},
{0x52, 0x22},
{0x53, 0x5e},
{0x54, 0x80},
{0x58, 0x9e},
{0x13, 0xe7}, // AWB on
{0x6f, 0x9f}, // Simple AWB


You should read the datasheet, instead of copying code from the internet.
I've only found the Preliminary Datasheet v1.4, but I haven't searched that long.
At least some parts of the code are wrong, so I wouldn't trust it altogether.
For instance:
{REG_COM11, 0x0A}, // enable auto 50/60Hz detect + exposure timing can be less...

Snip from the datasheet: COM11 Bit[4]: 0: Disable 50/60 Hz auto detection

